# Fill in default value on linked list

Tags: 2013, forms-7

I have a list called Projects with information about the different projects our department is taking on -- who as requested the service, what they have requested, etc.

I have another list called Resources where I assign the different people who will work on a project. In the Resources list people on the team also record what percent of their time they are working on this project and other bits of information.

When the intake person creates a new project they need to assign staff. I've added the resource list webpart to the project edit form and setup a connection to filter the resource list to only show the correct (if any) resources assigned to the project. Like this:

[image: My set up]

This is all working well. But when it comes time to enter a new resource it would be nice if the user didn't have to select the Project in the drop down. Is there a way for the filtered list to get its default value from the connection? So in this case "Big old project" would get entered into the next row when we start adding another resource?

It could be via a button "add new resource" or something like that. I'm just not sure where to look.